# JSTL | using c:when and and operator together

Tags: jstl

```
<c:when test="${empty youtube.id && authormode}">
    <img src="/libs/cq/ui/resources/0.gif" class="cq-video-placeholder cookiespecific" alt="" /> 
</c:when>
```

Any views on why this and condition is not working in test?

Answer (score 1):

Am hoping this to be under c:choose tag. Am assuming You need empty check for author mode as well unless its not boolean  like below:

```
 <c:when test="${empty youtube.id && empty authormode}">
```

Comment: `authormode` is boolean

Answer (score 1):

If the value for example is :

```
<c:set value="" var="youtube.id" />
<c:set value="true" var="authormode" />
```

then use && or "and" for this.

```
        <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${empty youtube.id and authormode}">
            <img src="/libs/cq/ui/resources/0.gif" class="cq-video-placeholder cookiespecific" alt="" /> 
         </c:when>
       </choose>
```